# To prove $0.4 \le \int_{0}^{1} x^{\sin x+\cos x} dx \le 0.5$

Tags: integration, algebra-precalculus, definite-integrals

Prove that  $$0.4 \le \int_{0}^{1} x^{\sin x+\cos x} dx \le 0.5$$

i have proved as follows:

when $x \in (0 \: \: 1)$ $$\sin x+\cos x \in (1 \:\:\:\sin 1+\cos 1)$$

and so $$x^{\sin x+\cos x} \in (x^{\sin 1+\cos 1} \:\:\: x)$$ $\implies$

$$\int_{0}^{1}x^{\sin x+\cos x} \in \left(\int_{0}^{1}x^{\sin 1+\cos 1} \:\:\:\int_{0}^{1} x\right)$$ that is

$$\int_{0}^{1}x^{\sin x+\cos x} \in \left(\frac{1}{\sin 1+\cos 1+1} \: \: \: 0.5\right)$$

But $\frac{1}{\sin 1+\cos 1+1} $ is approximately $0.4$  , is this proof correct?

Comment: Are you sure that $f(x)= \sin{x}+\cos{x} \leq \sin{1} + \cos{1}$? Because I at least get, for ex.
$f(.75) \approx 1.413$, and $f(1) \approx 1.382$.

Comment: Perhaps you can show that if $0 \leq x \leq 1 \Rightarrow 0 \leq x^{\sin{x} + \cos{x}} \leq x$, after which the integral would be easy.

Comment: This problem was asked on the CMI entrance test last year. You can find the solution [here](https://www.cmi.ac.in/admissions/sample-qp/ugmath2016-solutions.pdf) on page 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may note that $\sin x+\cos x =\sqrt 2\sin(x+\frac \pi 4)$.

By investigating the monotonicity of $\sin x$, we have, $\forall x \in [0,1]$, $\sin x+\cos x =\sqrt 2\sin(x+\frac \pi 4) \in [1, \sqrt 2]$.

Now can you go further starting from here?

P.S: To get the first identity, we can exploit the sine of the sum identity.

> $\sin (\alpha+\beta)=\sin \alpha \cos \beta+\cos \alpha \sin \beta$.

First, $a\sin \alpha+b\cos \alpha=\sqrt{a^2+b^2} (\sin \alpha {a\over \sqrt{a^2+b^2}}+\cos \alpha {b\over \sqrt{a^2+b^2}})$.

Obviously there must exist one $\theta$ where $\cos \theta = {a\over \sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$ and $\sin \theta={b\over \sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$, and this leads to $a\sin \alpha+b\cos \alpha=\sqrt{a^2+b^2} (\sin \alpha {a\over \sqrt{a^2+b^2}}+\cos \alpha {b\over \sqrt{a^2+b^2}})=\sqrt{a^2+b^2} (\sin \alpha \cos \theta+\cos \alpha \sin \theta)=\sqrt{a^2+b^2} \sin(\alpha+\theta)$

Comment: How did you get that first identity?

Comment: @TMM I edited the answer to explain how to get the first identity.

Comment: The first identity is obvious, so you don't need to explain, since TMM is not OP .

Comment: @TakahiroWaki I disagree. One doesn't necesariy need to give a detailed explanation as Huang did, but it would be rude to completely ignore a request of clarification on your answer.

Comment: ＠Ovi I don't say that. If we must prove such a fundamental theorem every time,  we don't go ahead. Actually this answer has gone to strange direction against this question. So you are definitely wrong.